# Crash due to device configuration change and a variable inside `ActivityResultContract`

Tags: android, activityresultcontracts

I have the following custom `ActivityResultContract` to allow the user to take a picture and receive the resulting image uri:

```
open class TakePictureActivityResultContract : ActivityResultContract<Uri, Uri?>() {

    private lateinit var imageUri: Uri

    @CallSuper
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Uri): Intent {
        imageUri = input

        return Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            .putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, input)
    }

    final override fun getSynchronousResult(
        context: Context,
        input: Uri
    ): SynchronousResult<Uri?>? = null

    @Suppress("AutoBoxing")
    final override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Uri? {
        return if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            imageUri
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm facing a crash problem due to the `imageUri` variable.
While the user is in the camera app and rotates the device, my app might be killed in background and the value stored in `imageUri` is lost, leading into a crash when the camera app returns with an `Activity.RESULT_OK` result.

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property imageUri has not been initialized

What's the best way to deal with this crash without having to get rid of the `imageUri` variable?

Comment: You don't have much of a choice but to get rid of the `imageUri` variable. The [already-existing `TakePicture` contract](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/86a812fface74760548e0557595fbb71c6027ebb:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.kt;l=275-301) specifically avoids holding onto `imageUri`, delegating that responsibility to the activity or fragment, which can then use `onSaveInstanceState()` to retain it across short-term process termination.